# Confusion Matrix in ArcGIS Pro not for accuracy but comparing two raster

Tags: arcgis-pro, confusion-matrix

I am wondering how to calculate or process confusion matrix on ArcGIS or other software for two raster data?

I have tried to do it on ArcGIS by create accuracy point (~700 random point) to get the matrix but it is actually not exactly comparing the two raster as it just 700 random point.

I don't know about Python and wondering if there is other way to figure it out?

Both of two raster has been clipped and reclassified into 378 x 378 cell per columns and rows, and also same classes.

I am wondering how can I overlay them and get the confusion matrix?

In the other way, can I just create 378x378 which is 142884 random points and will they sit on every cell of my raster?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: In R you would just use `table(r1, r2)` and it would return a confusion matrix. I am sure that there is something analogous in Python that can be done through NumPy. Please keep in mind that the filed of statistics is predicated on "sampling" a process. You do not need every pixel represented. The important consideration here is that you have your classes equally represented. This is referred to as a stratified sample and would be needed here. With very large rasters sampling is a bit of a necessity so, something that you should be familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am wondering if I will need to add a lot sample random points to get the confusion matrix in Arcgis. I actually not familiar with using Python on it so I am looking for the tools that I can use from those software. I have currently added 142000 point but it actually not perfectly covered all the cell.